# WiX installer - how can I determine that the NuGet package Manager is already installed in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, nuget

I have a custom installer based on WiX technology which is install three .vsix packages into Visual Studio 2012/2013. One of this packages is PostSharp - it needs NuGet Package Manager already installed in Visual Studio. The problem is that the Visual Studio 2013 has NuGet Package Manager by default, but Visual Studio 2012 hasn't.

So, I need to detect is NuGet Package Manager already installed in Visual Studio, and if not - install this package (.vsix) in my custom installer.

Is it possible in WiX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, download the [NugetPackageManager.vsix](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c), and reference it in your WiX project:

```
<Component Id="VSPackageComponent" Guid="E54DBAAF-4961-492C-AA8A-FFE3C4C77BA3">
      <VSExtension:VsixPackage File="VsPackageInstaller"
                               TargetVersion="11.0" <!-- VS2012 -->
                               PackageId="8cc311e8-5f48-4816-b1ee-6c873fe0dc71"
                               Vital="yes" Permanent="no" />
      <File Id="VsPackageInstaller" Name="NugetPackageManager.vsix"
                                    Source="NugetPackageManager.vsix"/>
</Component>
```

The magic is [VsixPackage](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/vs/vsixpackage.html) that does installation.

You will need to reference this DLL: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\WixVSExtension.dll`, and declare this schema in your wxs file:

```
xmlns:VSExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/VSExtension"
```

As far as the detection goes - I believe this should happen automatically with this approach. Give it a go, and report back :-)

Comment: My instinct would be to not author this into your installer but instead author it into the bootstrapper as a prereq redistributable.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: that can be done, but I think it will involve finding the actual *.msi/*.exe version of the `NugetPackageManager` (not sure how hard that task is). If it's *.exe, you will also need to create some kind of "is nuget package manager already installed" condition.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa: Yes, it works but with some minor changes: first - we need to include attribute Target="integratedShell" because it is required if the TargetVersion attribute is specified (I especially did not use a specific edition of Visual Studio because our customers can use Professional or Premium editions). Second - I use Vital="no" attribute to continue installation process if NugetPackageManager is already installed on customer's machine.